# Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом Generate Signed APK автоматически увеличивался на единицу versionCode?

Tags: android, android-studio, компиляция, build, android-manifest

Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом **Generate Signed APK**... автоматически увеличивался на единицу **versionCode**, чтобы не делать это вручную,.. просто, иногда забываешь об этом и загружаешь в **Google Play Console** версию со старым **versionCode** (что не допустимо!)

```
android:versionCode="X"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Решение 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21405744/5330439)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1

        versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=code.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            versionCode code
            versionName "1.1"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    // rest of android block goes here
}
```

[Решение 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571264/5330439) (использовать время)

```
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = date.format('yyMMddHHmm')
def code = formattedDate.toInteger()

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode code
}
```

Comment: TimurVI! Спасибо! Ну ты гений!!!... Сорри, а куда это воткнуть? (Решение 2, примерно, понял, а первое?)

Comment: @user: К сожалению, решения не мои. (в ответе присутствуют ссылки) До гения мне далековато. :).

Comment: в первом скрипте инкременитроваться будет всегда (run build.gradle), выведите отдельную таску, и оберните в проверку для signRelease, ну или просто +1 делать только когда запускается сборка Signed APK.
Во втором будет перезаписываться при каждом build.gradle.
Странно что ответ звучит в разрез вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю по другому. В основе идеи лежит использование номера версии из VCS.

В случае git делаем так:

```
//извлечение порядкового номера версии стартуя от HEAD
def getVersionCode = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            standardOutput = stdout
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', '--first-parent', '--count', 'master'
        }
        println("Build #"+stdout)
        return asInteger(stdout.toString("ASCII").trim())
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}

//присваиваем версию
def char[] patches='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz'.toCharArray()
def patch=1 //иногда бывает нужно определить патч внутри версии
def majorVersion=1
def minorVersion=0
def revision=getVersionCode()

defaultConfig {
    //blah-blah
    versionName = majorVersion + '.' + minorVersion + '.' + revision + patches[patch]    
    versionCode = 10000000*majorVersion+10000*minorVersion + 10*revision+patch
}
```

На выходе получим что-то типа:

```
versionName="1.0.25a"
versionCode="10000251"
```

Аналогичные скрипты можно написать и для SVN

**Update**

Инкрементирование версии будет при каждом `commit`. Отдельно можно также писать `githash` с тем, чтобы потом по логам восстановить какая именно версия упала и где. Когда юзеров много, не все вовремя апгрейдят версии - крайне полезная штука скажу я вам. Несколько раз реально выручала.

Comment: хорошая идея мы что-то подобное делаем только не в Gradle парсим, только в signingConfigs в release запихать. Ну или вопрос изменить. ибо Generate Signed APK

Comment: Согласен, но мне почему то ближе идея инкремента при каждом коммите